# Mailchimp Embedded Sign up form not displaying Captcha

Tags: email, recaptcha, mailchimp, display

I am using mailchimp embedded sign up form. It displays Email Account, First Name and Last Name, but captcha is not showing. I enabled captcha from Settings->List Name and Defaults.

What other steps do I need? Captcha is not showing in Preview Mode Option.

Please help, getting lot of fake emails. Double opt in is also enabled.

Comment: * BUMP. We have also experienced alot of spam emails. From the testing I've done turning on the "enable reCaptcha" under "List name and campaign defaults" does absolutely nothing. so frustrating. I'm using wordpress, and don't want to install an unnecessary plugin just to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Make sure its V2(checkbox) NOT V3. Documentation here: https://mailchimp.com/help/about-recaptcha-for-signup-forms/

Answer (score 0):

The Sign-up forms have invisible not checkbox re-captcha.

Source: https://mailchimp.com/help/about-recaptcha-for-signup-forms/#Enable_reCAPTCHA

You can find the summary in the below image.

[image]

Comment: Mailchimp specifically says that Embedded or Pop-Up Forms have the Checkbox variation. https://mailchimp.com/help/about-recaptcha-for-signup-forms/

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for an answer. Followed the instructions to enable the reCaptcha. After reloading website could not see it. After finally trying to submit the form it took me to a mailchimp external page with the reCaptcha showing. Makes sense when you think about doing some kind of server side check for a reCaptcha with minimal installation fuss.

Answer (score -2):

I've run into the same problem, and this is what I have found.

- I set the url to https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js, not sure if that helped, but it's one less spot for failure
- You might need to announce somewhere to allow for pop-up's to be allowed on the page when the captcha shows.  It seems that when that option is enabled that it opens up a new windows for the confirmation.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: This does not show how to add reCaptcha to embedded form.